# generate event after all messages have been processed

Tags: spring-integration

Is there a built in way in spring integration to generate an event when all messages has been processed in a context. For example, i have a file picked up by a `FileReadingMessageSource` and we split all rows in the file and the ask is to send an alert when all rows has been processed or connect some other dependent processing. Basically ability to wire a post processing component.

Answer (score 1):

The `FileSplitter` has an ability to emit start and end file markers. You can route them respectively and turn desired end message to the event. There is respective event publisher channel adapter , too.

See docs for more info:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#file-splitter

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#messaging-routing-chapter

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/event.html#applicationevent

As a general note: there is no built-in feature to determine the end of the messages flow. It is just an infinite stream. And mostly messages are not aware of each other and don’t affect each other. Only particular task  and specific business message can have such an indicator. Therefore it is good that you have shared that file splitting. Other use-cases might not come with end marker message .